# Store non realm object into realm database

Tags: android, realm

I have a third party library which has lot of data model created to capture the data in object. For example, to store record they have `Record` class, to store glucose readings they have `Diabetes` class.

Now as these classes are part of the library they are declared as follows

```
public class Record implements Serializable {        
}

public class Diabetes extends Record implements Serializable {
}
```

I want to use these classes and store it into realm. As realm has the constraint that it has to be extend from the `RealmObject`, I don't know how will I able to store the data captured in the classes declared by the library.

I can not do following as `Diabetes` did not extend `RealmObject`

```
Diabetes diabetes = new Diabetes() ;

 realm.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
            realm.insert(diabetes);
 });
```

So is there anyway to store the non realm objects into realm database? And if I re-create the same class in my app by extending `RealmObject` then how should I close the non realm object into realm object quickly?

Comment: Why are you extending Serializable?

Comment: as i have mentioned its declared in library , i have not declared it

Comment: Serialize them in json to store them in `String`. It's the only way I see to solve your problem.
Or you create Realm objects mirroring those classes and use something like Mapstruct to map properties

Comment: have you find a solution ? Did you try my suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class for Record, let's say RecordEntry and make it extend RealmObject.

Create a static function in RecordEntry which accepts a Record class as parameter and then convert this to a new RecordEntry object.

Example

```
static RecordEntry createRecordEntry(Record record) {
    return new RecordEntry(record.id, record.title);
}
```

Comment: i am hunting for some easy way rather than cloning the object , field by field

Comment: Good luck with that! :)

Comment: or Room. I've never had issues with this library but I keep hearing about problems and complexity with Realm.

Comment: I've only heard bad things about relations and especially recursive relations and nested relations with Room.

Comment: You can use MapStruct to map easily objects ;)
I agree that Realm objects are a pain in the *** for that